# На что заменить цикл for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Надо проверить, есть ли среди данных N чисел нули.

Формат ввода:

- Вводится число N, а затем N чисел.

Формат вывода:

- Выведите True, если среди введенных чисел есть хотя бы один нуль, или False в противном случае.

Мое решение:

```
print(any(int(input()) == 0 for _ in range(int(input()))))
```

Проверяющая система не хочет его принимать, хотя работает нормально. Опытным путем было выяснено, что не хочет принимать из-за цикла `for`.

Как изменить программу, чтобы избежать цикла?

Я пытался подключить библиотеку `_itertools_` как-то так:

```
from itertools import chain
print(any(int(input()) == 0 in chain(range(int(input())))))
```

Но что-то вообще не очень вышло...

Comment: Рекурсию использовать?

Comment: Поправил текст вопроса. Я просто не только тут интересуюсь.

Comment: и в чем проблема не понимаю? Чем рекурсия не решает данную задачу?

Comment: Про рекурсию не совсем понял, как с помощью нее можно это реализовать.

Comment: Ну стандартный метод программирования. Делаешь функцию checkHaveZeros, которой передаешь параметром массив, текущий индекс i (по дефолту 0). Затем try catch надеюсь в питоне есть, в трай кетч заворачиваешь arr[i] если не ноль, вызываешь checkHaveZeros(arr, i+1), если кетч значит массив кончился, возвращаешь False, если ноль, то возвращаешь True.
  
isThisArrayHasZero = checkHaveZeros(myArr, 0)
print (isThisArrayHasZero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coursera и курс от Вышки. Необходимо все сделать в функциональном стиле. Решается без дополнительных библиотек. Всё раскрывать не считаю правильным.
Сначала читаем первую строку и творим из нее *iterable*:

```
range(int(input()))
```

Далее подсовываем в *map* функцию

```
lambda x: int(input())
```

и полученный *iterable*.
А дальше для вновь полученного *iterable* применяем *map* c проверкой на равенство *0* и в финале any

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так:

```
In [21]: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [22]: any(map(lambda x: x==0, l))
Out[22]: False

In [23]: l = [0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6]

In [24]: any(map(lambda x: x==0, l))
Out[24]: True
```

или чуть более короткий, но слегка "извращенный" вариант - исходим из того, что `bool(num)` - истинно для любого ненулевого числа:

```
In [33]: l
Out[33]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [34]: not all(map(bool, l))
Out[34]: False

In [35]: l = [0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6]

In [36]: not all(map(bool, l))
Out[36]: True
```

Или совсем просто и элегантно (спасибо [LXA!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743297/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5/743324?noredirect=1#comment1138563_743324)):

```
In [42]: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [43]: not all(l)
Out[43]: False

In [44]: l = [0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6]

In [45]: not all(l)
Out[45]: True
```

Comment: мне кажется, можно даже сократить до: `not all(l)`

Comment: @LXA, да, действительно - так гораздо элегантнее подучается - спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой и легкий в понимании вариант:

```
n=input() #В данной программе не имеет значения, но для тестов необходимо
k=0
base=list(map(int,input().split())) #в условии не конкретно объяснилось как производится ввод, но обычно в задачах такого типа ввод идет через пробел
for l in base:
    if l == 0:
        k+=1
if k == 0:
    print("False")
else:
    print("True")
```

Comment: написано без циклов

Comment: я понял что проблема в цикле, и подумал сделать с циклом, но подругому

Comment: Проверяющая система хочет код без цикла в функциональном стиле в одну строчку